# no symbols loaded after visualSVN

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visualsvn

I have a project in vs2010 ,mvc web site c#.
I used to put break points and run the project and the code break on that breakpoints.
yesterday I added the project to visualSVN, since then I get error saying “The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.” 
I tried :
1. clean solution 
2. rebuild 
3. close open studio
4. it's in Debug mode
nothing seems to work ...

Comment: You can contact support@visualsvn.com for troubleshooting

Comment: Yes, same thing happened. Want to know, too... vs2012